# Maven and Jenkins - 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to learn Jenkins and Maven.

So Far what i have done:

1. Installed Maven and set `M2` and `M2_HOME` as env variables
2. Created a simple maven project from eclipse. --> Created a `.bat` file in which I am moving to the directory where the `pom.xml` file is located and running  `mvn clean package`. I run this bat file.

Everything went as expected till here.

3. Now I installed jenkins and created a item (or job) > Added build step as "Execute Windows batch command" . and entered the bat location.

But I am getting the following error:

```
*Started by user anonymous*
*Building in workspace C:\Users\abhi\ .jenkins\jobs\Maven\workspace*
*[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson6018913903543004539.bat*

*C:\Users\abhi\ .jenkins\jobs\Maven\workspace>C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\ma.bat*

*C:\Users\abhi\ .jenkins\jobs\Maven\workspace>E:*

*E:\>cd AllStuffLearning\EclipseWorkSpaces\MavenWorkSpace\MyMavenPrj\ *

*E:\AllStuffLearning\EclipseWorkSpaces\MavenWorkSpace\MyMavenPrj>chdir*
*E:\AllStuffLearning\EclipseWorkSpaces\MavenWorkSpace\MyMavenPrj*

*E:\AllStuffLearning\EclipseWorkSpaces\MavenWorkSpace\MyMavenPrj>mvn clean* *package *
*'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,*
*operable program or batch file.*
*Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure*
*Finished: FAILURE*
```

Answer (score 8):

The appropriate way is to define the location of such tools via the system configuration. Manage Jenkins and System Configuration and there you can do it like this:[image: Maven Installation in Jenkins]. Than there is no need to define properties etc. If you do this for different versions for example for Maven..than you can select the different version in your job like this:
[image: Maven Installation selection]

Comment: I tried Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Added Maven.  Still get the same error.

Comment: You need to have a a Job Type `Maven` and not using freestyle Type. And don't use shell calling or batch file calling for that.

Comment: @khmarbaise is it a better practive? not to use "shell script" to invoke maven (or gradle)? why not?

Comment: Either start maven with absolute path in your batch i.e. /usr/bin/mvn ... )  or inject the path variable with help of EnvInject, or use the maven plugin which respects the configured maven tool.

Comment: The shell script is always os dependent furthermore there are some functionality which is not available if you use for example Maven via Shell script. If you use it via Maven Type in Jenkins there are several convenience parts which are useful (test pickup, modules list etc.). There are some cases where it is a better idea to use it via shell, but it depends.

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you it worked after converting to Job type Maven.

Answer (score 8):

I have met the same error when I tried to run Maven project from Jenkins with an windows slave.Finally I've solved this issue by setting **M2_HOME** and **path** environments rights before the command `mvn clean test`.

[image]

Hope this help someone who still get the `mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command` error after setting `M2_HOME` environment and tool location.

Comment: This seems for me more of a workaround. If you have to specify this in every job, once you upgrade your maven version, you will have to do a lot of manual work to do the update.

Comment: Great, it resolved my problem, but need to change a little when set path, from "....\bin:%path%" to "...\bin;%path%". Thank you

Comment: I added the system variable, and removed the user variable, however i've an observation, jenkins behave differently on different server.

Jboss worked without this change, and  tomcat needs this change.

I confirmed by doing echo %PATH%

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68111559/5845739

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins you have "build environment" section (under "Configure", of course). There you have "Properties Content", and there you should add M2 and M2_HOME as well.

[image]

Comment: I Clicked on the Configure link inside the job, but i dont see any "build environment" section.

Comment: And under Manage Jenkins > Configure System , "Maven Configuration" section i have selected "use default Maven Settings" and "use default Maven global Settings

Comment: I don't think you need this when the installation is handled by jenkins itself.

Answer (score 0):

Even after setting the path for maven, I was getting the same result.
You can directly execute the cmd command as 
your/path/to/mvn/installation/mvn clean package

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of root cause,
Might be your Jenkins not recognizing your MAVEN path which is saved in windows environment variable. I have came across same issue, to mitigate this MOVE UP MAVEN path in environment variable, please refer screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add path to slave or ur node 
then go to folder containing pom.xml and excute mvn clean package

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because in Jenkins environment variable to the maven path and M2_home is not set

go to ->Jenkins ->system information->system variables

this path is taken by Jenkins when you install it on your system , i fixed it using reinstalling Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the M2_HOME and path in system variable in Windows earlier it as user level.

Answer (score -1):

Go to  ->Configure-> Build
Under 'Execute Windows Batch Command' please write the below code

```
set path=C:\Users\<name>\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin
c:
cd C:\Users\<name>\Selenium_SSCApplication\Maven_Selenium_SSCApplication
mvn clean test
```

Comment: you will loose all other path variable with this.