# "‘mvn’: No such file or directory" when trying to run mvn from Jenkins shell

Tags: linux, shell, maven, jenkins, centos

I started having this error after I uninstalled and reinstalled maven into a different location.

I have a Jenkins project in which my build step, Execute shell, invokes maven:

```
nohup mvn clean package &
```

But I keep getting this error

```
nohup: failed to run command ‘mvn’: No such file or directory
```

I've added maven's location to the `~/.bash_profile` (and also tried `.bashrc`) of the user jenkins

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

And if I'm logged in as jenkins, I can sucessfully run `mvn -version`. I can fix the issue by adding the above three lines to the Execute shell commands, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36525873/5961990), but since it was working without them before, I'd prefer to avoid them, and specially understand what's going on.

Could somebody clarify it to me?

Comment: First don't use `M2_HOME` nor use `M2` only extend the path with `/usr/local/apache-maven/bin` nothing more. Best is to configure tools in Jenkins and don't use hard coded path's inside jobs.